# How to install ruby mine Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, ruby, rails

I have already install RVM. Now I have download RubyMine-6.3.2.tar.gz From here http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/download/ , But still I am confuse How can I install it on my system. I am using Ubuntu 12.10. Please help me to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the GUI archive manager to extract the installation anywhere suitable

command line tar -xzf RubyMine-6.3.2.tar.gz

```
 /opt/rubymine
```

Then just create a launcher icon to this.

```
/opt/rubymine/bin/rubymine.sh
```

I just right click create a link move that link to Desktop and then use the .svg icon from /opt/rubymine/bin folder